# How to know the theme name currently used in my iGoogle page?

Tags: igoogle

As we may know, iGoogle page has themes and there's a huge theme collection for iGoogle. I currently use `Theme of the day` theme and sometimes I like one specific theme but not knowing what its name is. Trying to view it in the page source not helping me at all.

How can I figure out the name of a theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a link/button in the top right area labeled: `Keep this theme`. When you press that button it changes the label to: `Change theme from "themeName"`.